# How to remove corrupt SharePoint 2010 installation?

Tags: 2010, installation

Somehow the database on by dev box became corrupt and something happened to the SharePoint timer service.  I have tried for several hours now to repair the farm without luck and have thus reverted to uninstalling SharePoint and reinstalling it.

The main problem is that it will not let me uninstall it, the uninstaller crashes over and over and no matter what i do i cannot remove the server from the farm, repair the SharePoint installation, or even run the uninstaller.

I attempted to manually remove SharePoint in hopes of being able to reinstall it and i followed this guide: http://www.mysharepointadventures.com/2012/12/manually-removing-sharepoint-2010/

It starts to work when i begin to reinstall SharePoint however i keep getting the same error:

> The cabinet file 'PATCH_CAB' required for this installation is corrupt and cannot be used. This could indicate a network error, an error reading from the CD-ROM, or a problem with this package.

I have uninstalled all Office products from the server and i searched everywhere for a file PATCH_CAB, and came up empty.  I would really like to avoid having to reinstall the entire server if possible, so how can i clean it of SharePoint 2010 completely?

Answer (score 1):

There was no solution that i could find to effectively remove SharePoint from its corrupted state.  Reinstalling the entire VM was the only solution.

Answer (score 0):

Nukes. I'm not sure if this is a bad idea (probably is), but what about deleting all SharePoint related databases from SQL and attempt to reinstall again?

Comment: The installer will not even get past the base install.  It never gets to the point where it asks for database information.

Comment: @ps_md Hmm... would it be possible to try a system restore? Sorry, I have no experience yet with an installation corrupt that badly (thankfully).

Comment: Tried restoring the databases and files from an old backup, nothing worked...  Timer service would keep crashing and install / uninstall crashes...

Comment: @ps_md What about restoring the VM to a fresh state and re-installing sharepoint, then restoring the databases on that VM? (If it is on a VM)